# Передача ключа AES, шифрованного RSA, через http (node.js)

Tags: java, android, node.js, rsa, aes

Здравствуйте!
Ситуация следующая:
Есть зашифрованный алгоритмом AES файл, который выдает сервис на node.js. На клиенте файл принимает программа на android.
С этой частью всё ОК, но возникла проблема с передачей ключа и вектора инициализации для расшифровки файла на клиенте. Почитал в сети. что можно реализовать передачу путем шифрования ключа ключом RSA.
Тут первый вопрос: **хороший ли это способ?**
Стал пробовать реализовывать.
Делаю ключи на клиенте:

```
    keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
    keys = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    //Ключ в base64
    Base64.encodeToString(keys.getPublic().getEncoded(),Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Получается что-то такое:

> MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAO5x1devTOqcQUWrI_1fr_tAqWFEUR2D_4PqA-
>   FB-pfb5MdjIK5x0vZf25l-ZnwNwlMynSc8LchTplnZeGkJzI8CAwEAAQ==

Затем передаю ключ сервису в строке запроса.
Сервис получает точно такую же строку:

```js
//тут просто шифрование файла, в result находится JSON вида 
//{path1,path2,data:{key,iv}}
SFE.encryptBinary('./img/4.png', function(result){
   var cryptico = require('cryptico-js');
   //Вот тут получаем наш URL_SAFE base64
   act.with = act.with.replace(/-/g,'+').replace(/_/g, '/');
   //используем Cryptico-js для шифрования iv и key
   result.data.iv = cryptico.encrypt(result.data.iv, act.with).cipher;
   result.data.key = cryptico.encrypt(result.data.key, act.with).cipher;
   //Далее отдаем всй это на клиент
   callback(result, false, true);
});
```

Далее всё передаётся на клиент.

```
byte[] secKey = Base64.decode(pass,Base64.DEFAULT);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPrivate());
secKey = c.doFinal(secKey);//Возникает ошибка: E/_rsa: too much data for RSA block
```

Перепробовал кучу всего - не работает.Возможно,что я делаю какую-то ерунду:)

Буду благодарен за советы!

UPD: Получение ключа и вектора AES

```
function getKeyIV(key, callback) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, ivBuff) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var keyBuff = undefined;
    if (!key instanceof Buffer) {
        //defEnc = 'binary'
        keyBuff = new Buffer(key, defEnc);
    } else {
        keyBuff = key;
    }
    callback({
        iv: ivBuff,
        key: keyBuff
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте при расшифровке инициализировать `cipher` так: `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");`

Comment: @eugeneek результат тот же самый. Причем, с инициализатором "RSA" всё нормально, если шифровать/дешифровать внутри android. Я так думаю, что всё дело в скриптах сервера. Посмотрел исходники Cryptico-js, всё что смог понять, так это то, что там pkcs1padding и отдает он это вроде бы в base64...

Answer (score 1):

Это плохой способ: всякий, имеющий приложение может извлечь из него RSA-ключ. При помощи этого RSA-ключа он сможет расшифровать передаваемый AES-ключ и IV если перехватит траффик. Используйте SSL/TLS/HTTPS

Comment: Если у вас есть приложение, то вы и так получите расшифрованные  AES-ключ и IV, ведь именно это приложение и делает. А если вы имеете ввиду другую копию приложения, то там сгенерятся совершенно другая пара RSA.

Comment: Вы предполагаете некую генерацию RSA-пары, но не предполагаете что приложение не в тех руках может не получить никаких ключей. Странно...

Comment: Не совсем понял о чём вы. Каких ключей может не получить и почему?

Comment: @eugeneek да потому что нужно будет, к примеру, некий PIN вводить, который "плохой парень" не знает. И все, что он имеет - приложение и траффик.

Comment: Сначала вы писали, что любой может извлечь ключи из приложения. А теперь пишете, что ключей никаких не будет. Что-то не сходится. Но если нет ключей, значит и нечего расшифровывать.

Comment: Общая идея стоит в том, чтобы генерировать пару rsa для каждой отдельной загрузки. Публичный ключ передается сервису вместе запросом на скачивание. А в ответе отдаются шифрованные данные для aes и шифрованный файл.  Я же правильно понимаю, что нельзя расшифровать данные с помощью открытого ключа rsa, можно только закрытым?

Comment: @Megazilla Генерация RSA-пары - существенный момент, его нужно в вопрос добавить. Первый момент в этой схеме - MitM с подменой ключа, раз у вас незащищенный канал. Второй момент - авторизация при запросе на скачивание. Если любой сможет качать - нет смысла что-то шифровать вовсе.

Comment: С авторизацией всё хорошо, она произошла ранее ( просто тут нет смысла приводить полный код). Враг не пройдёт. А проблема с MitM осталась

Comment: @Megazilla используйте SSL/TLS/HTTPS